# Counter that shows 0 when it no longer has true items Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I will try to be a little more specific my problem is that when there are 2 articles of the same category and one is active and the other inactive it shows me 0 and tells me the one that is active I want it to show me 0 when there is no active item of that category of rest I do not hope to have explained myself better sorry for the inconvenience

```
$items = facturacion::select('clients_id', 'Status')
               ->selectRaw('count(CASE WHEN Status THEN 1 END) as c')
               ->groupBy('clients_id', 'Status')
               ->orderBy('clients_id', 'asc')                
               ->orderBy('Status', 'asc')
               ->get();

       $itemsA = [];
       foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
           $var = $value['c'];
           if($value['Status'] == false){
               if( 1 <= $var){
                   $var = '0';
                   array_push($itemsA, $var); 
               }
           }else{
               $var;
               array_push($itemsA, $var);
           }
       }
```

I leave here an image how it shows me 1 and 0 at the same time when a category has an active and deactivated item

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuj0W.png)

Comment: Do not post images of text.  Instead, copy and paste the text itself into the question.

Comment: What determines whether a `fracturacion` is active?  Is that the role of the `Status` column?  What determines whether `facturacion`'s are in the same category? Is that the role of `clients_id`?

Comment: It is in any case suspicious that you are grouping by `Status` and also computing a row count based on the value of `Status`, because `Status` is necessarily the same for all rows in each group.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sorry for the image...  yes status determines if it is true or false, clients_id would be the category so to speak

Comment: @JohnBollingerI really don't know what I'm doing wrong but it makes me count correctly my problem comes when there are 2 items in the same clients one active and false it shows me 0 and 1 at the same time from that same clients I want it to only show me 0 when there is none active item of that

Answer (score 0):

Your query groups by both `clients_id` and `Status`.  That is why you get two result rows per `client_id` when the base table contains at least one row with each `Status` for a given `client_id`.  Moreover, since `Status` is among your grouping columns, it must be the case that every base table row in each group has the same value of `Status`.  Therefore, your counts will always be either 0 or the number of rows in the group.

It sounds like including `Status` as a grouping column is simply wrong for your purposes.  You don't want to have separate results for separate statuses.  Rather, you want a single result for each `client_id` that reports on (in general) a *mix* of statuses.  And that being the case, it doesn't make sense to ask for a single status for each group, either, as the whole point is that there will not ordinarily be a consensus within the group.

So you probably want something more like this:

```php
$items = facturacion::select('clients_id')
               ->selectRaw('count(CASE WHEN Status THEN 1 END) as c')
               ->groupBy('clients_id')                
               ->orderBy('clients_id', 'asc')                
               ->get();
```

That will give you one result row per `client_id`, with the `c` column conveying how many base-table rows with that `client_id` have `Status` equal to true.

Also, if your plan is to choose from among the results only those categories that have at least one active row (alternatively: only those with no active rows) then you are making extra work for yourself by leaving that discrimination for the PHP side.  The database can easily do that for you.  For example, to select only those `client_id`s for which there is at least one active row, you might do this:

```php
$items = facturacion::select('clients_id')
               ->groupBy('clients_id')                
               ->orderBy('clients_id', 'asc')
               ->havingRaw('count(CASE WHEN Status THEN 1 END) > 0')
               ->get();
```

Comment: Oh really many very much thanks ... for taking the time to explain and help me ... distract with the solution I just intended what you just placed and my problem was solved and incidentally I acquired more experience of truth thank you very much...

Comment: thank you again for taking the time to answer, thanks to you I have learned a lot about this I hope to meet more people like you :D thanks again, I already have a clearer idea about it